# HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable when trying to download MNIST data

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, mnist

I'm trying to run code that I wrote a week ago on Google Colab (and it worked), but I'm getting this error now for some reason.

```
#libraries
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch.nn as nn

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True,
                             transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                               torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                               torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                 (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                             ])),
  batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
  torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, download=True,
                             transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                               torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                               torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                 (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                             ])),
  batch_size=batch_size_test, shuffle=True)
```

Output:

```
Downloading http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz to ./data/MNIST/raw/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-03d990013546> in <module>()
      6                                torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
      7                                torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
----> 8                                  (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
      9                              ])),
     10   batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True)

11 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong. Could they have moved the dataset?

**Update:**
Looks like you can't access the mnist dataset [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/) anymore